# No. of Observation inside BoxPlot, Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hello I am trying to display number of observation inside the boxplot by using matplotlib.

some fake data with example is:

```
data1 = [150, 155, 175, 200, 245, 255, 395, 300, 305, 320, 375, 400, 420, 430, 440]
data2 = [225, 380,325]
fake_data = pd.DataFrame([data1, data2]).transpose()
fake_data.columns = ['data1','data2']
bp = fake_data.boxplot()
```

I did not found proper way to do that . But I know there is way by using seaborn but i want to use matplotlib.

Comment: Data without column names lead to ambiguity. Which one should we consider as no. of observation ? And what is the error you are facing ?

Comment: sorry for incomplete datasets..actually number of observation is len of data i.e 15 and 3 that I want to put inside boxplot.

Comment: When in the plot do you want to insert the no. of obserations? Over the boxes?

Comment: @Bharath Just above median line is okey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its creates a bit of confusion to put the data above median line. Since you prefer that you can use the median data to locate the position and then add the sum of not null values in the plot as text i.e

```
bp = fake_data.boxplot()

x = np.arange(fake_data.shape[1])

noofobs = fake_data.notnull().sum().astype(int)

for tick,label in zip(x,bp.get_xticklabels()):
    bp.text(x[tick]+1, fake_data.median()[tick] + 1, noofobs[tick], 
            horizontalalignment='center', color='blue', weight='bold')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot Centered]

Comment: Thank you. You made my day.

Comment: Note the `+1` in the `[tick]+1` ... numbering of ticks is different than one would think.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same need of plotting box-plot by category (called `source`), but my data was in the "long format":

| source | value |
| --- | --- |
| data1 | 150 |
| data1 | 155 |
| ... | ... |
| data2 | 225 |
| data2 | 380 |
| ... | ... |

So I used `fake_data.boxplot(by = 'source')`. To show the group counts, I had to tweak @Bharath 's code. If you ever needed it please look at [my gist](https://gist.github.com/vojtech-filipec/da01dc1e20c9153ac5adc08581afc8ce). Hope that somone finds this useful.